# How to allow some specific users to login to Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have integrated my Gitlab server to my LDAP active directory on my internal network. I already have a JIRA server which is already integrated to this LDAP. I have used the same configuration/usergroup from JIRA in the Gitlab as well and my Gitlab is now successfully hooked to the LDAP.

Now i don’t want everyone who can login to Jira to login to the Gitlab account as well. I only want to allow some specific users.
Is there a settings in Gitlab configuration to achieve this thing?

Let me know if anyone can help on this. It will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two options:

1. Allow all JIRA users to login but autoblock all signups with [block_auto_created_users](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/#basic-configuration-settings). Then you have to manually enable new users.
2. Use the [user_filter](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/#basic-configuration-settings) option to restrict the users which are allowed to sign-up.  Here you have two additional choices. You can filter based on the username or better create a group on your LDAP server and then check the group membership with the `memberOf` function.